# MySQL can't connect using private IP address

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a fresh install of MySQL 5.7 on my Windows machine. When I make a connection using root@localhost, I am able to connect, but when i try to make a connection root@192.168.1.10 (the private IP address of my server) I  get the following error:

**mysql 5.7 access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.10'.**

I opened my my.ini file and added the line **bind-address=0.0.0.0**. I saved the file and restart my MySQL instance, but still not luck the same error appears.

I then tried:

```
**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**
```

This did not work either. I then tried to change the password for root to make sure I was using the correct password:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password')  WHERE  User='root';
```

But no luck.

Comment: We can all kinda guess what you want to do but could you please specify this in the question itself too? (e.g. ask a question?)

Comment: rem out skip networking yet ? Restart your daemon?

Comment: Do you have any other user with 'root'@ something? You might have one which is a more specific match. Do you have user(s) with empty username? You can check these by running: `select User, Host from mysql.user where User in ('root', '');` in mysql console.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled MySQL and now everything works.